# rpm + extract file after rpm install how to do?

Tags: linux

I build a simple rpm based on spec file
but my target is after I installed the rpm by rpm -Uvh  , is to put the test.sh file under 
/home directory, please advice what I need to change in the spec file in order to 
put the test.sh after I installed the rpm ?

remark: test.sh defined under /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES

```
 [root@linux /usr/src/redhat]# ls
   BUILD  RPMS  SOURCES  SPECS  SRPMS
 [root@linux /usr/src/redhat]# ls SOURCES 
   test.sh

 [root@linux /usr/src/redhat/SPECS]# more my_spec.spec

  Summary: An example tool. To show a simple rpm build of the tool.
  Name: test.sh
  Version: 6.2
  Release: 2
  Source: /root/test.sh 
  URL: http://www.gnomovision.com/cdplayer/cdplayer.html
  Group: Development/Debuggers
  BuildRoot:/var/test.sh
  License: OtherLicense
  %description
  %files

  [root@linux /usr/src/redhat/SPECS]# rpm -ba   /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/my_spec.spec 

  Processing files: test.sh-6.2-2
  Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /var/test.sh
  Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/SRPMS/test.sh-6.2-2.src.rpm
  Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/i386/test.sh-6.2-2.i386.rpm

  [root@linux /usr/src/redhat/SPECS]# rpm -Uvh  /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/i386/test.sh-6.2- 2.i386.rpm
  Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
  1:test.sh                ########################################### [100%]



      [root@linux /usr/src/redhat]# rpm2cpio  /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/i386/test.sh-6.2-2.i386.rpm | cpio -idmv
      1 block    ( I dont get the test.sh file?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need an install step where you copy the script to the home directory
something like that, not tested !

```
%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}

mkdir -p %{buildroot}/home

cp %SOURCE0 %{buildroot}/home

%file
/home/test.sh
```

Comment: is correct here. Be aware in some distros the rpm macros and available variables might be different, for example I use the variable $RPM_BUILD_ROOT instead of the macro above on PLD-Linux, but otherwise the I would do exactly that procedure.